# Is there a python function for getting the same result to php.hash?

Tags: php, python, hash

I want my Python `crc32` function get the same result with PHP `hash` function. Where is the Python module in this world? My heart is almost collapsed at this moment.

The PHP function is:

```php
hexdec(hash('crc32', 'hi', false))
```

The Python function I used:

```
binascii.crc32('hi') & 0xffffffff
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function_exists('abs');
function_exists('hexdec');
function_exists('hash');
$hash = hexdec(hash('crc32', 'hi', false));
echo $hash. "\n";
?>
```

Output:

> 4049932203

Python:

```
import binascii
binascii.crc32('hi') & 0xffffffff
```

Output:

> 3633523372

Comment: CRC is a family of algorithms that work in the same way. They get input data, and they use a second value - 32 bits in case of CRC32 - that tells them how to do the checksumming. Looks like the defaults for the second value are different in PHP and Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092226/how-to-calculate-crc32-with-python-to-match-online-results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate CRC32 with Python to match online results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092226/how-to-calculate-crc32-with-python-to-match-online-results)

Comment: "My heart is almost collapsed at this moment." Ok, relax. The PHP crc32 hash is little different, try using "crc32b" in PHP instead, .e.g. `hexdec(hash('crc32b', 'hi', false))`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the same hash algorithm. For example:

PHP

php > `echo hash('sha512', 'foo');`

Result:

`f7fbba6e0636f890e56fbbf3283e524c6fa3204ae298382d624741d0dc6638326e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7`

Python

`import hashlib
hashlib.sha512(b'foo').hexdigest()`

Result: `f7fbba6e0636f890e56fbbf3283e524c6fa3204ae298382d624741d0dc6638326e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7'`

Comment: thank u bro. But when u test crc32, u will get the different result

Comment: but if use `crc32` function only in php return same result in python `<?php 
// PHP program illustrate the  
// crc32() function 
  
$str1 = crc32("hi"); 
  
// print without %u 
echo 'Without %u: '.$str1."n"; 
  
// print with %u 
echo 'With %u: '; 
  
printf("%un", $str1); 
?> `

Comment: result `Without %u: 3633523372nWith %u: 3633523372n`

Comment: Bro, hash('crc32', 'hi') in php is not same as crc32("hi"), u can test it . Thanks bro anyway.