# How do I generate id column based on row values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

It would be great if someone could help me to address below concern.

[image]

How do I populate ID column based on values in respect row for all columns? Something like crc32 or MD5 algorithms.

Comment: You would like to hash the data from, c1, c2, c3, c4 using MD5 or other hashing algorithms and put the value in Id, am I right?

Comment: correct just trying to generate hash or natural key based on row values.

Comment: Can you provide your `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hashlib, you could take the dictionary of row values and translate that into an md5 hash.

```
import hashlib

df['Id'] = [hashlib.md5(str(x).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for x in df.T.to_dict().values()]
```

Comment: Thanks @oskros It seems your code is working for me, but need to test more with different cases. One question what does "T" stands in "df.T.to_dict()?

Comment: `T` stands for transpose. So basically I am switching the rows and columns of the dataframe. The reason I do this, is because when creating a dictionary using the built-in pandas function, we get a list of dictionaries with row values for each column. Instead we want a list of dictionaries with column values for each row - This is solved with the transpose

Comment: thanks for the clarity @oskros. If I want to use CRC32 alogo can use hashlib?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092226/how-to-calculate-crc32-with-python-to-match-online-results