# CRC computation port from C to Python

Tags: python, c, porting, crc32

I need to convert the following CRC computation algorithm to Python:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int Crc32Table[256];

unsigned int crc32jam(const unsigned char *Block, unsigned int uSize)
{
    unsigned int x = -1; //initial value
    unsigned int c = 0;

    while (c < uSize)
    {
        x = ((x >> 8) ^ Crc32Table[((x ^ Block[c]) & 255)]);
        c++;
    }
    return x;
}

void crc32tab()
{
    unsigned int x, c, b;
    c = 0;

    while (c <= 255)
    {
        x = c;
        b = 0;
        while (b <= 7)
        {
            if ((x & 1) != 0)
                x = ((x >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320); //polynomial
            else
                x = (x >> 1);
            b++;
        }
        Crc32Table[c] = x;
        c++;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned char buff[] = "whatever buffer content";
    unsigned int l = sizeof(buff) -1;
    unsigned int hash;

    crc32tab();
    hash = crc32jam(buff, l);
    printf("%d\n", hash);
}
```

two (failed) attempts to rewrite this in python follow:

```py
def crc32_1(buf):
    crc = 0xffffffff
    for b in buf:
        crc ^= b
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 if crc & 1 else crc >> 1
    return crc ^ 0xffffffff


def crc32_2(block):
    table = [0] * 256
    for c in range(256):
        x = c
        b = 0
        for _ in range(8):
            if x & 1:
                x = ((x >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320)
            else:
                x >>= 1
        table[c] = x
    x = -1
    for c in block:
        x = ((x >> 8) ^ table[((x ^ c) & 255)])
    return x & 0xffffffff


data = b'whatever buffer content'

print(crc32_1(data), crc32_2(data))
```

Using the three routines on thee exact same data yield three different results:

```
mcon@cinderella:~/Desktop/3xDAsav/DDDAedit$ ./test5 
2022541416
mcon@cinderella:~/Desktop/3xDAsav/DDDAedit$ python3 test5.py 
2272425879 2096952735
```

As said: `C` code is "Golden Standard", how do I fix this in Python?

Note: I know I can call `C` routines from Python, but I consider that as "last resort".

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Print out the generated table, print out `x` after each character, check when and how it starts to differ.

Comment: FYI, there's a CRC32 implementation in the Python standard library: [`zlib.crc32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32). Just [mind the difference between signed/unsigned CRC32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30092226/11082165). The standard library implementation matches your `crc32_1`, and `0x100000000 - zlib.crc32(...) - 1` matches the C implementation.

Comment: What's the equivalent of `Crc32Table` in the Python version?

Comment: @Barmar Looks like they embedded `Crc32Table` and `crc32tab` inside their `crc32_2`.

Comment: @tkausl: generated tables (`crc32_2`) are identical. I am trying to follow the two running in parallel, but it's not easy :/

Comment: @Barmar: Brian61354270 is fully correct. I embedded the table inside `crc32_2()` and generated tables there and in `C` match.

Comment: If you're going to try to port code, using similar variable names would make things easier to compare.

Comment: @Barmar: agreed, sorry; truth is I don't like choices in `C` code (I did not write it) so I "fixed" stuff in Python... not thinking I would have needed help. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: Funnily, there's actually two CRC32 implementations in the standard library. There's a second at [`binascii.crc32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.crc32)

Comment: @Brian61354270: It seems I can use my `crc32_1()` (or `zlib`'s implementation) provided I allow for signedness. I still wonder where I goofed in `crc32_2()`, but that's minor. If you reformat in a proper answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of porting your own CRC32 implementation, you can use one from the Python standard library. For historic reasons, the standard library includes two identical<sup>1</sup> CRC32 implementations:

- [`binascii.crc32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.crc32)
- [`zlib.crc32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32)

Both implementations match the behavior of your `crc32_1` function:

```
import binascii
import zlib

>>> print(binascii.crc32(b'whatever buffer content'))
2272425879

>>> print(zlib.crc32(b'whatever buffer content'))
2272425879
```

To get a result matching the C implementation from the question, [you just need to apply a constant offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092291/11082165):

```
>>> 0xffff_ffff - zlib.crc32(b'whatever buffer content')
2022541416
```

As a bonus, these CRC32 functions are implemented in efficient C code, and will be much faster than any equivalent pure-Python port.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the `zlib` module is only available when CPython is [compiled with zlib support](https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/#install-dependencies) (which is almost always true). In the off chance that you're using a CPythion build without zlib, you won't be able to use the `zlib` module. Instead, you can use the `binascii` implementation, which [uses `zlib` when available and defaults to an "in-house" implementation when its not](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/binascii.c#L767).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @nicomp It is according to what the OP wrote in the comments.

Comment: It's not actually an arithmetic offset. It's a final exclusive-or. It just so happens that for that _particular_ constant `0xffffffff ^ x` is equal to `0xffffffff - x`, assuming `x` fits in 32 bits (which it does in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Two small changes to your code produce the desired results:

```py
def crc32_1(buf):
    crc = 0xffffffff
    for b in buf:
        crc ^= b
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 if crc & 1 else crc >> 1
    return crc


def crc32_2(block):
    table = [0] * 256
    for c in range(256):
        x = c
        b = 0
        for _ in range(8):
            if x & 1:
                x = ((x >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320)
            else:
                x >>= 1
        table[c] = x
    x = 0xffffffff
    for c in block:
        x = ((x >> 8) ^ table[((x ^ c) & 255)])
    return x & 0xffffffff


data = b'whatever buffer content'

print(crc32_1(data), crc32_2(data))
```

prints:

```
2022541416 2022541416
```

In the first function, the final `^ 0xfffffff` was removed. That is not there at all in the C code.

In the second function, the initialization `x = -1` was replaced with `x = 0xffffffff`. The `x = -1;` works in C, since `x` is 32 bits, at least for the compiler being used by whoever wrote that. (An `int` in C is almost always 32 bits nowadays, even though the standard permits it to have as few as 16 bits. It would be more portable to use `uint32_t` instead.) In Python, `x = -1` has an infinite supply of one bits to shift down.

By the way, you don't need that final `& 0xffffffff`.